# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_open()

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Magento onestep checkout is giving this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function geoip_open()

on this line of code`$geoip = geoip_open($pathToDB, GEOIP_STANDARD);`

and the whole function is this

```
 public function processGeoIP($ip)
    {
        include_once Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'lib' . DS . 'Magestore' . DS . 'Onestepcheckout' . DS . 'Geoip' . DS . 'geoipcity.inc';
        include_once Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'lib' . DS . 'Magestore' . DS . 'Onestepcheckout' . DS . 'Geoip' . DS . 'geoipregionvars.php';
        $pathToDB = Mage::helper('onestepcheckout/geoip')->getDatabasePath();

        $geoip = geoip_open($pathToDB, GEOIP_STANDARD);
        $data = array('ip' => $ip);

        $address = geoip_record_by_addr($geoip, $ip);

        if ($address) {
            $data['code']        = $address->country_code;
            $data['country']     = $address->country_name;
            $data['region']      = (isset($GEOIP_REGION_NAME[$address->country_code][$address->region]) ? $GEOIP_REGION_NAME[$address->country_code][$address->region] : $address->region);
            $data['city']        = $address->city;
            $data['postal_code'] = $address->postal_code;
            $data['country_id'] = $address->country_code;
            $data['region_id'] = $this->getRegionIdByCode($address->region, $address->country_code);
        }

        geoip_close($geoip);
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Did you [install GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php)?

Comment: Its working before suddenly this error is happening its came with one step checkout

Comment: We'll phrase it differently then... Is GeoIP currently installed?